# Update templates without restarting the app in CppCms

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, cppcms

In [this tutorial](http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_hello_templates), it says:

> Dynamic linking is a little bit more tricky, but it is much more
>   powerful as it allows you to load skins without relinking the
>   application. **You can even update your application without needing to
>   restart it.**

So I decided to put it to the test, and while the app was running, I replaced `libmy_skin.so` file with another skin.

The skin in the running app did not change.

Is the statement above incorrect, or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn this option on:

http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_config#views.auto_reload

Comment: ah. got it. so, basically, for production environments, dynamic linking is useless

Comment: It is not useless, but I would not recommend using dynamic realoading as there is a small performance penalty.